# Is microUSB connector used for charging inherently lighter than USB-C solution?

Tags: usb, usb-c

Let's say you have a device that uses USB just for charging, like a rechargable light torch (like this: https://www.ultralightoutdoorgear.co.uk/equipment-c3/lighting-c30/head-torches-c162/petzl-bindi-headlamp-p8589 ).

1. Does using microUSB instead of USB-C save weight (even when it is one gram)?
2. And if they weight the same, would a solution with USB-C be able to use features like USB-PD?

I happen to own the torch and given the small size of the battery, I am always puzzled by the fact that it takes about two hours to charge. Is it because it has no circuitry in order to save weight and the lowest current is used?

Comment: It's a matter of cost, not weight. Unless it's going to be loaded onto a rocket, I don't think the weight of a flashlight is something they tend to optimize for.

Comment: I think they do optimize for it. There is a lot of people who decide mainly based on weight when buying hiking equpment, me included. Plus if it were USB-C, I might need one cable less, saving additional grams (that is why I asked in the first place).

Comment: I have a hard time believing they'd give much weight to a few grams of difference. Maybe consider the weight of heavy components like the battery, but I doubt they'd consider the weight of electronics unless they're for an extremely weight-sensitive application like a satellite. Regardless, the USB-C connector is more expensive than a micro-B connector, and probably marginally heavier though I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Well, maybe not the manufacturer but I am sure there is a market that cares about weight tremendeously. Like for example here: https://backpackinglight.com/forums/topic/59694/

But it is true I was was mainly interested in the question due to the possibility of not having to have a microUSB cable at all. It feels kind of backwards to buy stuff with microUSB in 2020...

Comment: A USB-C to micro-B adapter might be lighter than a full cable, if you're that worried about weight. Definitely smaller. Slightly less convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl; dr: USB-C is no benefit for this application. Micro-B is more than enough and will be cheaper / lighter.

The flashlight (torch in Brit-speak) is self-limiting its charge rate based on the battery size and its "1C" charge rate. If you exceed that rate the battery can be damaged through overheating.

More about charging rate here: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/what_is_the_c_rate

And here: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

A small headlamp like the one shown would not benefit from USB-C power delivery, as it has a correspondingly small battery and thus, a limited charging rate.

The specification for this lamp is a 680mAh battery. If we assume it's one cell (3.8V), then we can infer that the max 5V draw for a 1C charge is:

- 680mA * 3.8V/5V = 516mA from USB

So ordinary USB 2 (500mA) is pretty close to adequate for this lamp; and USB3 (900mA) is more than enough. Note also that USB BC 1.2 can support up to 2.4A. That's plenty.

Comment: Hm, and so are the connectors for microUSB actually lighter? As I mentioned in the comment above, having USB-C would mean I would not need to take a microUSB cable with me at all, which would actually be the real gain from the change to USB-C.

Comment: I didn’t read that comment, was only looking at your posting. Micro USB by itself is a simpler, lighter, less expensive connector than USB-C. If you didn’t need USB3 or power delivery, using only micro USB would be lighter.

Comment: Well, it was my very firsrt question in my posting:-). But thanks for the answer, so one either saves grams on the cable that one does not eed (probably more savings) or on the connecter,cannot have it both ways it seems:-).

Answer (score 0):

> I am always puzzled by the fact that it takes about two hours to charge. Is it because it has no circuitry in order to save weight and the lowest current is used?

Cost optimization.  A common charging rate on older generation lithium ion batteries (hence, cheap lithium ion batteries) is 0.5C.  If you charge half of the capacity per hour, you'll take 2 hours (or actually a bit more since charging slows down towards the end).  Faster charging is certainly possible, but it would require them to buy newer batteries and controllers, which would cost more.